# Selecting the maximum value of a column where the column name is supplied in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert some very round-trip heavy C# code to a single block of SQL script that implements a table reseed. This is non-production code that basically clears test data from tables and reseeds them as part of a test suite.

My problem occurs when I try to select the maximum value of an identity column where the column name is held in a variable ('@IdentityColumnName' in the script below).

When this script executes, I get the following error on the line that contains MAX(@IdentityColumnName)...

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

...which I assume is happening because SQL assumes I'm asking it for the MAX of the variable and not treating it as the name of a column.

```
-- Assume that some (or all) existing values have been removed from the table prior to this...
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '__Foo' AND COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IdentityColumnName AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @IdentityColumnValue AS BIGINT

    SELECT TOP 1 @IdentityColumnName = [COLUMN_NAME] FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = '__Foo'
    SELECT @IdentityColumnValue = ISNULL(MAX(@IdentityColumnName), 0) FROM [__Foo]

    -- Reseed the table with either 0 (if it's empty) or the maximum value already in the table
    DBCC CHECKIDENT ('__Foo', RESEED, @IdentityColumnValue)
END
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to have SQL treat that variable as the name of a column so my query will work? I've tried building up a string and executing that with EXEC, but that led to the rigmarole of capturing the result of EXEC and I want to confirm there isn't an easier way to accomplish this.

- The code will need to work against SQL Server 2008 R2 if that makes a difference.
- This is just non-production test stuff; it doens't have to adhere to any best practice.
- There's usually a DELETE FROM with optional WHERE xyz executed immediately before the reseed. Sometimes the table ends up empty, other times it still has a few rows in it.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL if you want the column to be dynamic.

Comment: ` SET @SQL = N'
  DECLARE @IdentityColumnValue AS BIGINT;
  SELECT @IdentityColumnValue = ISNULL(MAX(' + QUOTENAME(@IdentityColumnName) + N'), 0) FROM [__Foo]
  DBCC CHECKIDENT (N''__Foo'', RESEED, @IdentityColumnValue);';
 EXEC (@SQL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, dynamic SQL was required and you cannot get MAX to treat the variable as a column name. The solution I ended up with is a combination of the solutions provided by Dan and Gordon with a few tweaks to get it to do what I wanted.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '__Foo' AND COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @IdentityColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @IdentityColumnValue AS BIGINT

    -- Select the name of the first column into @IdentityColumnName (and just assume it's the identity column)
    SELECT TOP 1 @IdentityColumnName = [COLUMN_NAME] FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = '__Foo'
    -- Create a dynamic SQL statement to determine the maximum value in that column (or 0 if there are no rows and MAX returns NULL)
    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT @IdentityColumnValue = ISNULL(MAX(' + QUOTENAME(@IdentityColumnName) + '), 0) FROM [__Foo]'
    -- Execute the dynamic SQL and put the result into the @IdentityColumnValue
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@IdentityColumnValue BIGINT OUTPUT', @IdentityColumnValue OUTPUT

    -- Reseed the table using the value determined above
    DBCC CHECKIDENT ('__Foo', RESEED, @IdentityColumnValue)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL snippet example:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'
DECLARE @IdentityColumnValue AS BIGINT;
SELECT @IdentityColumnValue = ISNULL(MAX(' + QUOTENAME(@IdentityColumnName) + N'), 0) FROM [__Foo];
DBCC CHECKIDENT (N''__Foo'', RESEED, @IdentityColumnValue);';
EXEC (@SQL);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need dynamic SQL.  But, your conversion problem is happening on character columns.  You *could* do something like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT @IdentityColumnValueStr := CAST(MAX(@IdentityColumnName) as NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM [__Foo]';
SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '@IdentityColumnName', QUOTENAME(@IdentityColumnName));

DECLARE @IdentifyColumnValue NVARCHAR(MAX);

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@IdentityColumnValueStr NVARCHAR(MAX)', @IdentityColumnValueStr = @IdentityColumnValueStr;

PRINT @IdentityColumnValueStr;
```

You an then very carefully convert the value back to a number, if you really believe the value is numeric.